# Enviar un JSONObjectrequest en Android studio con klotin

Tags: php, mysql, json, kotlin

Soy bastante novato, y estoy intentando hacer un login en Android Studio utilizando kotlin. El problema está en que yo escribí un código kotlin en el que pedía un string request, y sin embargo en php mando un JSON. Por lo que no me funcionaba. He tratado de investigar en diversos lugares sobre como mandar un JSONObjectrequest desde Android Studio para poder obtener así lo de php. Pero no lo he conseguido. También he buscado algunos login hechos que utilizaban el JSONObjectrequest, pero no funcionaban correctamente. He probado varias cosas y nada. Me ha resultado imposible. Me gustaría saber como mandar un JSONObjectrequest correctamente y que mi código pueda funcionar. Cualquier ayuda es útil, incluso algún video de Youtube donde lo explique claramente. Muchas gracias a todos.
El código de android studio es el siguiente:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import java.util.HashMap

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {
    var nombreusuariologin: EditText? = null
    var contraseñalogin: EditText? = null
    var enviarlogin: Button? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        nombreusuariologin = findViewById(R.id.nombreusuario)
        contraseñalogin = findViewById(R.id.contraseña)
        enviarlogin = findViewById(R.id.enviarlogin)
        enviarlogin!!.setOnClickListener { validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.47/Registro/loginapp.php") }
    }
    private fun validarUsuario(URL: String) {
        val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST,
            URL,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                if(response != null && response == "true"){
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@Login,
                        "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            },
           Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@Login,
                    error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val parametros: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                parametros.put("nombre",nombreusuariologin?.text.toString())
                parametros.put("password",contraseñalogin?.text.toString())
                return parametros
            }
        }
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Y este el código php:

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre');
    $records->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message ='';
    if (count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
        $success = True;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }else {
        $success = False;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }
};
?>
```

Comment: Si eres nuevo en Android, es demasiado importante revisar el LogCat, que error se muestra? ahí puede encontrarse la respuesta a tu problema. Recuerda que la url a la que realizarás la petición debe ser leía por cualquier dispositivo, http://192.168.1.47/Registro/loginapp.php veo que no puedo accederla , probablemente este es el principal problema,, saludos.

Comment: @Elenasys en el LogCat no da ningun error porque no hay nada mal. Hay un if que pone if(response != null && response == "true") que pase a la pantalla y sino que no pase, y como no se envia nada porque envio un json y pido un stringrequest no pasa.Y respecto a lo de que la url, creo que no puedes acceder porque está alojado en mi ordenador/servidor porque todavía no la he publicado. ¿Puede ser eso?

Comment: la respuesta no esta devolviendo valor, el problema es que esta url no funciona: http://192.168.1.47/Registro/loginapp.php si funciona en tu pc no significa que va a funcionar en el dispositivo.

Comment: @Elenasys  Y cómo puedo hacer para que todos los dispositivos puedan leer esa URL. ¿La tengo que publicar si o si, o hay algún modo de hacerlo sin publicarlo?

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿Y como puedo solucionarlo? ¿Es necesario publicarlo?

Comment: El administador de esa url debe saber como realizarlo, si liberas tu aplicación a los usuarios y esta url solo funciona en tu pc, los usuarios no podrán usar correctamente tu aplicación.

Comment: @Jorgesys Ya sé que debería saber hacerlo. Pero no tengo ni idea. ¿No sería usted tan amable de enseñarme a hacerlo, o decirme alguna página donde lo expliquen o algo? Si no me lo explicas, seguiré sin saberlo. Muchas gracias.